# How can I group by column value in a yii query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I have a data table with 7 columns and 400 records. One of them is budget. I want to group the 400 rows by budget so that I get an array like this:

```
[budget]=>array(
          [0]=>array(
              [column1]=>'1',
              [column2]=>'sand'
              ),
          [1]=>array(
              [column1]=>'2',
              [column2]=>'clay'
              )
          )
[budget2]=>array(
          [0]=>array(
              [column1]=>'3',
              [column2]=>'silt'
              ),
          [1]=>array(
              [column1]=>'4',
              [column2]=>'stone'
              )
          )
```

So far I have been playing around with Yii's CdbCommand and CdbDataReader and PHP's PDOStatement but nothing is working right.  I tried the following code

```
public function actionBidCostByBudget(){

        $command = Yii::app()->db
        ->createCommand()
        ->Select('*')
        ->From('bid_cost')
        # ->Query()
        ;
        echo '<pre>';
        echo get_class($command);
        $pdostatement=$command->getPdoStatement();
        if($pdostatement) echo get_class($pdostatement);
        # print_r($statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));
        # print_r($command->readall());
        # print_r($statement->fetch());
        # $columnsArray = BidCost::attributeLabels();

        //print_r($rowsArray);
        //$this->layout='\\layout';
}
```

The attempts to print_r all print out with nothing. getPdoStatement equals nothing. I have been trying to use PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP as per the Php.net website, but it does not work either because I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

One of Yii's strengths is it's [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/), so why not use it?

Make your budget to a separate table (so you can generate a model from it). Reference it from your "datatable".

```
CREATE TABLE budget (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE datatable(
    column1 TEXT,
    column2 TEXT,
    ...
    budget_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(budget_id) REFERENCES budget(id)
);
```

Next generate models with Gii, and now you can use your newly made relations like this:

```
$budget = Budget::model()->findByAttributes( ["name"=>"budget2"] );
foreach( $budget->datatables as $dt ) {
    echo $dt->column1;
    echo $dt->column2;
}
```

*(I know. Not the array you asked for. Sorry if I'm way off with this.)*

Comment: Sorry, but I am not a fan of ActiveRecord. It takes up too much memory. Secondly, either you misunderstood my table or you have an error in your syntax. A table has three columns: ID, Description, Budget; plus several rows (example:4). I need an array that outputs first by budget and then by the column values for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the bottom line is that I was not able to find a way to do this right thru Yii, so I did it with a more hands-on approach.

The first thing I did was basically initiate a database connection *thru Yii*.

```
$command = Yii::app()->db   //outputs CDbConnnection
```

The next thing I did was get a PDO class from the connection:

```
$pdoinstance = $command->getPdoInstance();  //outputs PDO class
```

From this point, it was help obtained from PHP.net and another question posted on this forum:

```
$pdostatement=$pdoinstance->prepare('SELECT BUDGET_CODE, 
PAY_ITEM, ITEM, DESCRIPTION FROM bidcost');
$pdostatement->execute();
//default fetch mode could not be set
# $pdostatement->setfetchmode(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
//returns array
$testarray=$pdostatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```